The card item in CSS isn't flipping as expected when used backface-visibility property
There's the HTML code:


section {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.card-item__side {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-item {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card-item__side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-item:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
<section>

  <div class="card-item">

    <div class="card-item__side front">

      <div class="card-info">
        <h2>Here is the information</h2>
        <p>Flip the card</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card-item__side back">

      <div class="card-info">
        <p>The card is flipped</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>



So when I am trying to hover over a card on its front side it shows me the backside content including the front side content being mirrored (instead of front side being disappeared as I expected when I used backface-visibility property. What's the problem and how to solve it?
Maybe the problem is with the HTML markup, the elements laid out in the wrong way?

Works for me! Cannot see any problem.

Add .card-item__side { will-change: transform; } so that the browser optimizes your transformations.


section {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.card-item__side {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  will-change: transform;
}

.card-item {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card-item__side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-item:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
<section>

  <div class="card-item">

    <div class="card-item__side front">

      <div class="card-info">
        <h2>Here is the information</h2>
        <p>Flip the card</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card-item__side back">

      <div class="card-info">
        <p>The card is flipped</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>




Thank you really much, that helped me solve this problem! I'll look up and learn more about that will-change property
